# MySQL - stored procedure set and round

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to write [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) `set` and `round` in one line. That is, is there any option to write a stored procedure like this in MySQL?

```
SET x = ROUND'(Y,2);
```

I have also tied the method like this

```
DECLARE z INTEGER;
DECLARE x FLOAT;
SET z = y*100;
SET x = z/100;
```

But it is also not working. Is there any way to round a variable in MySQL when we set the value to that variable?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with doing:

```
SET z = ROUND(y*100, 2);
```

You can always [write your own function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-udf.html) to do this, and call it `MYROUND()` or whatever, if you'd like.

But you can't overload/replace an existing MySQL function.

Comment: "not working" means nothing. did it destroy your server? kick your dog? insult your mother? return an error message?

Comment: SET z = ROUND(y*100,2); NOT working. It is npt returning any error but the output is not round to 2 decimal places